# Can Emscripten be used to port a C library to a plain old JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I have a C library, which has no dependencies other than libmath. I would like to transpile it to a JavaScript module using Emscripten, that could be used in pretty much any JavaScript execution environment in any of the normal ways:

```
const myModule = require('myModule'); // In Node.js
import { MyClass } from 'myModule'; // Webpack, etc.
```

...Or even just included using `<script>` tags in the browser. But the Emscripten docs seem to be very focused around having a `main` function. I would simply like to port this library over to JavaScript so that consumers of my API can write their own scripts in JavaScript and use my API as if it were never written in any language besides JavaScript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need a `main` function, you can specify which functions to export with the `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS` setting. But note that Emscripten now compiles to WebAssembly by default, which means starting it is asynchronous. In order for you to be able to just `require` the module like any other Node package, you'll want asm.js output instead. Possibly setting the `WASM=0` setting for Emscripten will work, otherwise some other process may be required.